# Adding active class with styled component not working

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components, gatsby

So My function is:

```
function onClickChange(props) {
  let MyDiv = document.getElementById('myDIV')
  let InterfaceDesign = document.getElementById('interfaceDesign')
  if (MyDiv.style.display === 'none') {
    MyDiv.style.display = ''
    InterfaceDesign.classList.add('active')
  } else {
    MyDiv.style.display = 'none'
    InterfaceDesign.classList.remove('active')
  }
}
```

From this function in DOM I can see that it's getting the active class. But from my styled component:

```
const FirstDivElement = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  &:hover {
    background-color: #e6007e;
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }
  &:active{
    background-color: #e6007e;
  }
`
```

It is not getting the style of &:active

My div element is:

```
<div id="interfaceDesign">
            <div onClick={onClickChange}>
              <ListItems
                headingText="Interface Design"
                backgroundImage={props.secondBackgroundImage}
              >
                <Img
                  style={{
                    height: '50px',
                    width: '50px',
                  }}
                  sizes={props.interfacedesign}
                />
              </ListItems>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="myDIV" style={{ display: 'none' }}>
            <InterfaceDesign
              secondBackgroundImage={props.secondBackgroundImage}
              interfacedesignMagenta={props.interfacedesignMagenta}
            />
          </div>
          </div>
```

Can anyone please help? Thank you in advance :D

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you should note that using the DOM as the source for your state is against the way React works (state flows from parent to child, and the DOM is handled by React).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're providing styles for the [:active pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active), which is only used for when an element is being activated (e.g. during a mouse click). You probably want to change from `&:active` to `&.active` in your styled component CSS.

Also, you should note that you usually would alter styles based on props with Styled Components. You *can* do what you're doing, but it's less common.

Answer (score 3):

You can do by passing a prop `active` in your `FirstDivElement` and update your `onClick` method.

here an example :

```
const FirstDivElement = styled.div`
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: ({ active }) => active ? #e6007e :#000;
    &:hover {
        background-color: #e6007e;
        transform: scale(1.05);
    }
    &:active{
        background-color: #e6007e;
    }
` 


onClickChange = () => {
    let MyDiv = document.getElementById('myDIV')
    this.setState({
       active: MyDiv.style.display === 'none' 
    })
}


render(){
    const { active } = this.state
    return(
        <div>
            <div onClick={onClickChange}>
                {/* content */}
            </div>
            <FirstDivElement active={active}>
                {/* content */}
                 <div id="myDIV" style={{ display: 'none' }}/>
            </FirstDivElement>
            <button onClick={this.onClickChange}> Click </button>
        </div> 
    )
}
```